# Command re-assigned

Tags: zsh, function

I found a Bash script snippet earlier with which to echo a string to stderr:

```
echoerr() { echo "$@" 1>&2; }
echoerr hello world
```

This remained in my clipboard, and when I wanted to edit a file (with VIM) I accidentally pasted this snippet again instead of the file name:

```
vim echoerr() { echo "$@" 1>&2; }
echoerr hello world
```

It seems to have re-assigned `echoerr` to `vim`:

```
$ where vim
vim () {
    echo "$@" 1>&2;
}
/usr/bin/vim
```

Also, attempting to open a file with VIM now just echos the file name back:

```
vim path/to/some-file
```

Prints:

```
path/to/some-file
```

**What happened?** (I'm running zsh inside tmux)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `zsh` allows you to define function with multiple names. From `man zshmisc`:

```
function word ... [ () ] [ term ] { list }
       word ... () [ term ] { list }
       word ... () [ term ] command
              where term is one or more newline or ;.  Define a function which
              is referenced by any one of word.  Normally, only  one  word  is
              provided;  multiple  words  are  usually only useful for setting
              traps.  The body of the function is the list between the  {  and
              }.  See the section `Functions'.
```

Answer (score 4):

You have managed to create a function called `vim()`. This is possible because zsh allows you to create a single function with more than one name at the same time

```
% vim dud() { echo ran dud function }
% dud
ran dud function
% vim path/to/some-file
ran dud function
```

Note how `vim()` and `dud()` both got set as functions.

You can kill off the mistaken one by unsetting the function def for it like so:

```
% unset -f vim
```

Now `vim path/to/some-file` should open your editor.

Comment: +1 for ```unset -f```, although before knowing this I just started a new terminal session.